# Listview in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, listview, tabular

I need to make a listview like the pic shows, but in Java.

E.G. from Delphi `Listview`

[image: Tabular GUI component]

I've tried to use `JList` but it didn't work quite right, I couldn't make columns, just rows. Could someone help me?

Comment: It looks more like a JTable (swing) or a TableView (JavaFX)...

Comment: I think you should try to make a distinction between Java -- which is both a runtime environment and a programming language -- and the various graphical user interface APIs that work with Java.  Neither the Java Language Specification (language) nor the Java Memory Model (runtime) contain any language about listviews.  To make use of such a feature, you need to access an API that works with Java.  Java 7.25 has built-in support for two GUI libraries: Swing and JavaFX (currently at 2.2).  Thus, your question isn't as much about Java as it is about the particular GUI library.

Comment: Take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using JTable and do your own research for how to use JTable.